# How to avoid git sync of prisma .env files

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma

When I set up `prisma` in my project, by following this [article](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls), I can set up `.env` and set database url and password.

After that,DB connection was established and some tables were migrated. But I am wondering that Are there any problem to add `.env` to `.gitignore` ?
password is hardcoded and this credentials are not pushed.

If someone has experienced this problems or know other options, will you please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommended that the `env` files are added to `.gitignore`.

Executing `npx prisma init` should create a `.gitignore` file and a `.env` file along with creating `prisma` folder. The default behaviour is that the env file gets added to the .gitignore file so that the credentials are not accidentally pushed to source control.

Here is a [reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/environment-variables/managing-env-files-and-setting-variables) for using multiple env variables or using prisma without any env variables.

There should be no issues on adding `.env` to `.gitignore` file.